# passing properties between a simple java project and spring boot project

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties

**Context:**
There are 2 projects

1. Java project (no framework) --- p1
2. Spring boot project --- p2

I have added p1 jar as a dependency in p2. I am calling one **method(m1)** from one of the classes of p1 in p2 (**m1** takes 2 parameters)

**Issue**
m1, in its definition, has a variable which is from a property file (a key value pair), Is it possible to have that property in p2 (in application.properties) and expect p1 to pick it up?
or should I define a property in p1 itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If Project 1 is a jar, and if the property is going to be constant then you should have properties configured in P1 itself.
- If you are going to make changes often, you can't build the jar every time so you should configure your spring boot property file to inject the property into the jar.